# Xamarin Studio 6.3 with mono 4.8.. suddenly debugger not working

Tags: debugging, xamarin, mono, breakpoints

I cannot hit breakpoints in Xamarin Studio since yesterday afternoon. Restart, clean, rebuild still no joy. Using Mac OSX. I am aware this issue is in version 5 of mono. But I am on 4.8. Is anyone having the same problem. Very frustrating.

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found any solution?

Comment: I had to remove my local copy of the project and pull a new one from the repo. I suspect I did a copy and paste and I must have introduced a hidden character to my code somewhere. So all I did was to bump the local copy and pull a new one from the dev branch.

Answer (score 0):

Dump your local copy and pull a new copy from the repo.